# Swift Number Of Weeks in Month

Tags: swift

I'm using Swift 5. I'm trying to get the number of weeks in a month. Jan 2021 prints 6 weeks, but May prints 5 weeks. I'm thinking the problem is `firstWeekday` is set to 1.  Is there a way to get the number of weeks in a given month without setting `firstWeekday`?

```
var localCalendar = Calendar.current
localCalendar.firstWeekday = 1
let weekRange = localCalendar.range(of: .weekOfMonth, in: .month, for: dateFormatter.date(from: monthName)!)
if let weekRange = weekRange {
    print("\(monthName) has \(weekRange.count) weeks.")
}
```

Comment: No month (except sometimes February) holds an exact number of weeks, so you need to specify what answer you expect and why. What does "number of weeks in a month" even _mean_?

Comment: Apples calendar app has their month change size based on the number of weeks.  Or maybe its not the number of weeks, but number the number of "Mondays" for example in a month.

Comment: So your question is just How many rows does it take to display this month? That’s a good question but it isn’t what you asked

Comment: Incidentally I do not know what you many about May. It needs 6 rows.

Comment: @matt I think OP meant that their code prints 5, but the expected output is 6

Comment: @Sweeper Ah! I see what you mean the OP means.

Comment: I can NOT reproduce your issue. `let may = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2021, month: 5).date!`
`Calendar.current.range(of: .weekOfMonth, in: .month, for: may)!.count // 6` 
 returns 6 for me

Comment: I had the same issue, .count was returning the wrong number of weeks, possibly because the range of available weeks is up to 6. Using .last gave the proper value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you do not want the number of weeks in a month at all. You want the number of rows in a calendar printout.

The formula for the number of rows needed to represent a month on a standard Gregorian-style calendar is as follows.

Start with the number of days in the month. Add to that the number of *blank* days before the start of the month, beginning with Sunday. For example, January 2021 is 31 + 5 = 36, because it's 31 days long but 5 days (Sunday thru Thursday) are not part of it before the start. To put it another way: the first day of January 2021 is a Friday; that is day 5 of the week if we call Sunday day 0, so we get 31 + 5.

Now integer-divide by 7. We need at least that number of rows. So (31+5)/7 using integer division is 5. The question is: is that *all* the rows we need?

To find out, get the *remainder* of that division. If it is not zero, add another row. So (31+5)%7 is 1, which tells us that one more day needs to be accommodated so we need another row. That makes 6.

Thus:

```
// `startingOn` pretends that Sunday is day 0
func rowsNeededForMonthWith(numberOfDays n: Int, startingOn i: Int) -> Int {
    let (quot,rem) = (n+i).quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 7)
    return quot + (rem == 0 ? 0 : 1)
}
```

Here are some quick sanity tests:

```
// January 2021
rowsNeededForMonthWith(numberOfDays: 31, startingOn: 5) // 6
// But suppose it had 30 days?
rowsNeededForMonthWith(numberOfDays: 30, startingOn: 5) // 5
// Or suppose it had started on Thursday? (cf July 2021)
rowsNeededForMonthWith(numberOfDays: 31, startingOn: 4) // 5
```